Calling Azure Document Intelligence API inside VSTO Excel Addin
It's likely a result of my lack of knowledge about VSTO addins, but I am unable to get Azure Document Intelligence calls to work at all from within the application. I made a regular console app, just to test that my configuration and key was working properly and I could call the API no problem, it's only when I try to use it in my Addin project.
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

using Azure;
using Azure.AI.FormRecognizer.DocumentAnalysis;


namespace ExcelAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {


        static string key2 = "KEY";
        static string endpoint2 = "ENDPOINT";

        static string imagepath = "Path on disk";

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            //Authenticate
            AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(key2);
            DocumentAnalysisClient client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(new Uri(endpoint2), credential);

            //Send file on local disk to OCR
            LaunchOCR(client);
        }



        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }


        public void LaunchOCR(DocumentAnalysisClient c)
        {
            AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = c.AnalyzeDocument(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-invoice", (Stream)File.Open(imagepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));

            AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;
           
        }


        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        
        #endregion
    }
}


Like I said, this sort of code ran fine outside of the addin, but it throws the following: https://pastebin.com/RE8QX0Us
I called a simple REST API successfully to see if it was related to Excel accessing the internet, so I really don't know if it's a code problem, network problem, config problems. I've also confirmed that addins are loading correctly, I used the example Microsoft provides to create a new row on save and that worked just fine

The error suggests some network related issue, but provided that your console app was run on the same machine which is producing the error in Excel then this shouldn't be the issue. Especially since you're able to make a rest call over the internet.
Add-ins typically run in a Single-Threaded Appartment, which can effect async operations. You could try using Task.Run() and Wait() to have the request run on a separate thread.
public void LaunchOCR(DocumentAnalysisClient c)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            AnalyzeDocumentOperation operation = c.AnalyzeDocument(WaitUntil.Completed, "prebuilt-invoice", (Stream)File.Open(imagepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
            AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;
        }).Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        // Handle the AggregateException
        ae.Handle((x) =>
        {
            if (x is RequestFailedException rfe)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"Error analyzing document: {rfe.Message}");
                return true;
            }
            // Handle other exceptions
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {x.Message}");
            return true;
        });
    }
}

The only other thing I can think of is, if you're console app is attached to your compiler, such as Visual Studio, and you're running elevated as administrator, try also elevating Excel to see if there's some privileged operation going on.

Hi, thanks for the response. Unfortunately none of those proposed solutions fixed the problem, they all throw the same sorts of errors. So strange, ran as administrator, same with excel, tried Task and the exact same thing
